# Calling a JSP Function from another jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

I have create a simple application on jsp..

In my global function jsp file, I have created functions as follows:

```
<%! public double calcB(double w, double h){
                double B = 0;

                return B = (w / (h * h));

            }


            public String calcClassif(double B){
                String classifi = null;

                  if(B >= 30)
                      classif = "Obese";
                  else if(B >= 25)
                      classif = "Overweight";
                  else if(B >= 18.5)
                      classif = "Normal";
                  else 
                      classif = "Underweight";

                  return classif;

            }

        %>
```

Now in my my index.jsp file, I have written the following:

```
<%@include file = "globalFunctions.jsp" %>

        <% Boolean submitted = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("isSubmitted"));
           double we = 0, he = 0;
           if(submitted){

               weight = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("w"));
               height = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("h"));                                 
           }
        %>

        <h3>BMI Calculator</h3>

        <form action = "index.jsp" method = "post">
            <input type ="hidden" name = "isSubmitted" value = "true"> 
            Weight: <input type = "text" name = "w"> <br> <br>
            Height: <input type = "text" name = "h"> <br> <br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Compute"> <br> <br>

            BMI: <%= calcBMI(we, he) %> <br> <br>
            Classification: <%= classification %>
    </form>
```

When I execute the application, the classification is not working.. How do I call the method to display me the correct classification ? 
Please help.. Thanks

Comment: It is really not a best practice to include business logic in a jsp. The method you have created will be in another servlet after the servlet container has compiled it from the jsp. You could declare it `static` and try to guess the class name, good luck with that.

Comment: Actually, I have just started with Java EE.. So, I'm a newbie :p 

Can you provide an enlightenment with the above if you can see what's wrong please ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never assign a value into `classification`. You may try this:

```
<%@include file = "globalFunctions.jsp" %>

        <% Boolean submitted = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("isSubmitted"));
           double we = 0, he = 0;
           if(submitted){
               weight = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("w"));
               height = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("h"));
               bmi = calcBMI(we, he);
               classification = calcClassif(bmi);
           }
        %>

        <h3>BMI Calculator</h3>

        <form action = "index.jsp" method = "post">
            <input type ="hidden" name = "isSubmitted" value = "true"> 
            Weight: <input type = "text" name = "w"> <br> <br>
            Height: <input type = "text" name = "h"> <br> <br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Compute"> <br> <br>

            BMI: <%= bmi %> <br> <br>
            Classification: <%= classification %>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I forgot that I should have assigned a variable to the classification..

Now it works :)  Thanks a lot.. 

P.S - I'm unable to vote you up, since I am a newbie here and don't have enough reputation.. :/ But I've marked your answer with the green acceptance

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your JSP is compiled by your servlet container, it is compiled under different names every time. This makes it hard to use a JSP page function in another JSP page. I would recommend you to start using servlets and POJOs for your data processing needs.

Anyway, you don't have any variable named `classification` (index.jsp:21), therefore it is not displayed and the server logs an error to the console, and not to the client like PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your help too.. 

I'm still a beginner in Java EE ! :D